# Spring Boot 2 + Angular 8 - Wildcard URL pattern

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to build an application with spring boot and angular to support users to send only username to access their home page.

Wonder if this works with some sort of wild card implementation but not sure.

http://localhost:8080/personA

http://localhost:8080/personB

http://localhost:8080/personC

.
.
.
.
http://localhost:8080/personN

Could you please guide me through this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This community wants to help you, but will not deliver code based on a few sentences and a technology list. In order to get a good answer, please read [ask] and provide an example of whet you have tried ([mcve]), and a clear description of what you want solved.

Comment: have a look at spring boot antd path variables, and while you are at it, look at REST service best practices.

Comment: @JoSSte thanks for your response... willl look into it..